# How to maintain a valid order book in kraken exchange with node,js

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

How's it going?
I got the example order book code in python (https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027677512-Example-order-book-code-Python-) and translate it to javascript to run in node. But the book is wrong, it doesn't remove all old prices level. I'm sending my code below. I'd like help to solve this issue.

```
const websocket = require('ws');
const ws = new websocket('wss://ws.kraken.com');
const api_book = {'bid':[], 'ask':[]};
const api_depth = 10;

const api_output_book = () => {
    bid = api_book['bid'].sort((x, y) => parseFloat(y[0])-parseFloat(x[0]));
    ask = api_book['ask'].sort((x, y) => parseFloat(x[0])-parseFloat(y[0]));
    console.log ('Bid\t\t\t\t\tAsk');

    for (let x=0;x<api_depth;x++) {
      console.log(`${bid[x][0]} (${bid[x][1]})\t\t\t${ask[x][0]} (${ask[x][1]})`);
    }
}

const api_update_book = (side, data) => {
    data.forEach((e) => {
        let index = api_book[side].findIndex(o => o[0] == e[0]);
        if (parseFloat(e[1]) > 0){
            if(index < 0){
                api_book[side].push([e[0],e[1]]);
            } else {
                api_book[side][index] = [e[0],e[1]];
            }
        } else {
            api_book[side].splice(index,1);
        }
    });

    if(side=='bid'){
        api_book['bid'].sort((x, y) => parseFloat(y[0])-parseFloat(x[0]));
    } else if(side=='ask'){
        api_book['ask'].sort((x, y) => parseFloat(x[0])-parseFloat(y[0]));
    }

}

ws.on('open', open = () => {
    ws.send('{"event":"subscribe", "subscription":{"name":"book", "depth":'+api_depth+'}, "pair":["XBT/USD"]}');
    console.log('Kraken websocket connected!');
});

ws.on('message', incoming = (data) => {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf8'));

        if (data[1]) {
            if (data[1]['as']) {
                api_update_book('ask', data[1]['as'])
                api_update_book('bid', data[1]['bs'])
            } else if (data[1]['a'] || data[1]['b']) {
                if (data[1]['a']) {
                    api_update_book('ask', data[1]['a']);
                }
                if (data[1]['b']) {
                    api_update_book('bid', data[1]['b']);
                }
            }

            api_output_book();
        } 


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have also been playing around with Kraken's order book and came up with this solution using Angular. I also added a few console logs into the mix so that you can take it and run it in the browser. Hope this helps!

```
// variables
private ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.kraken.com')
public asks = [];
public bids = [];

// Web Socket open connection
this.ws.onopen = () => {
    this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(this.message));
    console.log('Trade WS with Kraken connected')
}

// Fires when new data is received from web socket
this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    if (!data.event) {
        if (data[1]['as']) {
            this.asks = data[1]['as'];
            this.bids = data[1]['bs'];

            console.log('Initialised Book');
            console.log(this.asks, this.bids);


        } else if (data[1]['a'] || data[1]['b']) {
            if (data[1]['a']) {
                this.update_book(this.asks, 'ask', data[1]['a']);
            }
            if (data[1]['b']) {
                this.update_book(this.bids, 'bid', data[1]['b']);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Updating Orderbook
update_book (arr, side, data) {
        if (data.length > 1) {                                      // If 2 sets of data are received then the first will be deleted and the second will be added
            let index = arr.findIndex(o => o[0] == data[0][0]);     // Get position of first data
            
            arr.splice(index, 1);                                   // Delete data              
            arr.push([ data[1][0], data[1][1] ]);                   // Insert new data  
            console.log('Delete and Insert');
        } else {
            let index = arr.findIndex(o => o[0] == data[0][0]);
            console.error(index);
            if (index > -1) {                           // If the index matches a price in the list then it is an update message
                arr[index] = [data[0][0], data[0][1]];  // Update matching position in the book
                console.log('Updated ' + index);
            } else {                                    // If the index is -1 then it is a new price that came in
                arr.push([data[0][0], data[0][1]]);     // Insert new price
                this.sort_book(arr, side);              // Sort the book with the new price 
                arr.splice(10, 1);                      // Delete the 11th entry
                console.log('Insert Only');
            }                   
        }
        this.sort_book(arr, side);                      // Sort the order book
}

// Sort Orderbook
sort_book (arr, side) {
    if (side == 'bid') {
        arr.sort((x, y) => parseFloat(y[0]) - parseFloat(x[0]));
    } else if (side == 'ask') {
        arr.sort((x, y) => parseFloat(x[0]) - parseFloat(y[0]));
    }
}
```

I would also recommend just having a look at this resource:
[How to maintain a valid orderbook](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027821131-How-to-maintain-a-valid-order-book-)

Comment: Please don't hesitate to let me know if there is any way that we can improve upon this code!